# Questions asking for manual identification of fonts?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I've seen several question related to fonts on SU. While I do believe that fonts can be considered software related, I've noticed that a subset of those questions asks superusers to **manually** identify font from provided set of letters.
 In my opinion such questions do not belong on SuperUser. If the question was about some software which would identify fonts, then that would be OK, but I believe that questions such as ones I am complaining about here are as related to SuprUser as question where the OP would post a link to a mp3 file containing part of a song and ask us what's the name of the song.

I ask you what is your opinion on this.

Here are some examples:

https://superuser.com/questions/56865/

https://superuser.com/questions/118252/  closed as duplicate of above question

https://superuser.com/questions/167760/

Comment: It may be worth redirecting users to sites like http://www.identifont.com/ or others where users can be asked questions to identify fonts and/or upload images to automate the process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree that fonts are originally a typography topic.

If a question is about "how to install a font", or "why this font is not printing, from my computer", then this is a computer related question, and it can be asked on Super User.

However, eye identification of a font has nothing to do with computers. Such questions should be closed indeed as off-topic, in my opinion.

Comment: Be my guest @Gnoupi