# List guess-the-application as off-topic in the FAQ list

Tags: support, asking-questions, scope, faq-update-request

[The answer to "Are 'Guessing Game' type questions allowed on SU?"](https://meta.superuser.com/a/6074) says guessing-the-software questions are banned. Fine, but that information should be in [the FAQ list](https://superuser.com/faq) under "and it is not about" or under "What kind of questions should I not ask here?". Otherwise, a new user will (as [I just did](https://superuser.com/q/595532/83729)) check the FAQ list, find nothing wrong with his question, ask an off-topic question, and get it closed.

Comment: A tip of the hat to [techie007](http://superuser.com/users/23133/techie007) for [suggesting](http://superuser.com/questions/595532/identify-the-ui#comment732350_595532) I ask this here.

Comment: Not sure about this. We need to strike a balance between a reasonably complete FAQ and an FAQ that is short enough that it actually gets read. And I cannot remember a second question of this kind… For comparison, we also don't explicitly mention our ban of 'Hackintosh' questions, and we get a lot more of those.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I agree, and perhaps it makes sense to deal with these on a per-question basis. For example, does [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/593759/random-two-tone-notification) qualify and should it be closed?

Comment: @Karan Looks like an unusual troubleshooting question. I'd consider it a *practical, answerable question based on an actual problem that you face* in line with the FAQ. It's neither too localized nor NARQ due to (as of now) presumably having a real answer.