# Motherboard beep codes

Tags: discussion

After a quick search on SU for 'beep codes', I can't find a general community wiki to answer beep codes.

Is there one, should we make one?

Comment: Isn't that very device/vendor-specific?

Comment: Good point @slhck, but I don't *think* so really - there are only a handful (as far as I know)... Most of the questions I read in the search were for AMI, Award, Phoenix and NEC. So, even if having a wiki just covering 'the most popular' would probably answer a lot of questions

Comment: Sure, sounds reasonable. I'm not really a PC hardware expert. Note that officially, we don't do CW anymore. A self-asked and -answered question would be fine though, and nothing prevents you from making your answer CW if you want to encourage others editing it. If such a question would serve as a canonical end point for other questions (which usually end up with the same troubleshooting advices), then I'm all for it.

Comment: Just FYI, we used to have a `[beep]` tag, which I personally took out to the shed and killed.

Comment: Cool, I will wait until I see if I get any votes (or not) first :) Thanks again slhck, your comments (as always) are helpful and relevant.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, I have a rodent problem which could use your expertise  :) Why did you destroy it, due to abuse of the tag or over use (if the latter then it makes more sense to create this page I guess)

Comment: @DaveRook The tag was being applied to anything that could involve beeping or other noises, like fans, HDDs, monitors, ...

Comment: I personally consider this no different from my hardware identification question - so you get an upvote, and entirely unofficial, non mod-hatted support for this idea.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, which question/? Link (please)?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer basically, write something that refers back to past questions in the (self) answer, and we can close other questions as dupes of the question. http://meta.superuser.com/a/7651/10165 is also worth reading, since that's the answer/comment stream that lead to my community faq answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the comment by Journeyman Geek, I decided to do it!

The link can be found here: [Why does my computer beep when I turn it on? What are these beep codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes)

Hopefully it will be of some use.